# Conditional probability as a primitive concept

Tags: probability-theory

Most of the popular axiomatizations/theories of probability define conditional probability as a ratio involving unconditional probability.
Therefore, conditional probability is second class to unconditional one in such axiomatizations, and I suspect may suffer from some irregularities because of that.

I am looking for alternative axiomatizations that have conditional probability as a primitive concept.

I am aware of a few of them at this moment:

1. J. M. Keynes. A Treatise on Probability, London: Macmillan, 1921
2. K. Popper. The Propensity Interpretation of Probability, British Journal of the
   Philosophy of Science 10, 25–42, 1959
3. More references from http://philosophy.anu.edu.au/sites/default/files/Hajek%20-%20Conditional%20Probability.pdf

What I am looking for is some kind of overview: was this approach fruitful or not, are there any recent developments, what are the major differences among attempted axiomatizations.

Comment: Maybe Alfred Renyi, or Richard T. Cox's _Algebra of Probable Inference_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In a sense all probabilities are conditional.

Comment: Michael, I agree that all probabilities are conditional in a sense, but the usual axiomatizations (e.g., Kolmogorov's) define unconditional probabilities, and only add conditional ones as a derived concept.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've found this: http://philosophy.anu.edu.au/sites/default/files/Hajek%20-%20Conditional%20Probability.pdf
Reading through the references cited on the first page.

Comment: Also: Popper functions (no Wikipedia article on them, shocking!).

Comment: Popper proposed an *alternative axiomatization of probability*?

Comment: http://155.97.32.9/~mhaber/Documents/Course%20Readings/Popper_Propensity_BJPS1959LITE.pdf

Comment: Ach so. One cannot say the paper is very prolixe about the advantages of the construction it proposes/recalls in its last pages.

Comment: Yes, I feel lost among these disparate papers from different authors, trying to make sense - was there anything useful in this idea? If yes, why did it die?

Comment: The answer to your second question might follow from the answer to the first. (Unrelated: Please use @.)